# Maximizing a quadratic objective subject to sum constraints

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming

Is it possible to solve the following problem?

$$
\max \,{x^ \top }x \\[0.1in]
st: \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{x_i} = 1} \\[0.1in]
0 \le x_i \le 1
$$

Intuitively it happens when any one of the $n$ $x$'s is $1$ and all others are zero. Is there a way to prove this ?

It is easier to see that the minimum occurs at each x taking the value $1/n$ using Lagrange multipliers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be proven using the [Karush-Kuhn-Tucker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions) conditions.

For each inequality $x_i \le 1$ introduce its associated Lagrange multiplier $\mu_i$ and for the equality constraint $\sum x_i = 1$ introduce its associated Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$. The KKT conditions have three parts:

a) stationarity

$$ \nabla \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n \mu_i \nabla \left(x_i-1\right) + \lambda \nabla \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i-1 \right)$$

b) primary feasibility

$$\sum x_i = 1$$

c) complementary slackness

$$\mu_i(x_i-1) = 0$$

Stationarity immediately becomes
$$ 2x_i - \lambda - \mu_i =0 , i=1, \ldots,n.$$

From complementary slackness we notice that it is impossible to have all $x_i=1$ since that would violate primal feasibility; in fact, only for one unique index $k \le n$ we have $x_k=1$. Stationarity then implies $\mu_k=2, \lambda=0$, while for all other indices $i \ne k$ we obtain $x_i=\mu_i=0$.

Comment: Why did we ignore that all $\mu_i=0$ from complementary slackness. That would give us a minimum with $\lambda$=n/2

Comment: @baudolino It seems that you forget inequalities $x_i\geq0$.

Answer (score 1):

This follows immediately from the convexity of $ x^2$, which tells you that you want to select values from the endpoints.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how convexity implies that "we select values from the endpoints". Is there a mathematical justification?

Comment: @user2142 The mathematical justification is that the function is convex in each variable, and that the maximum of convex functions occur at the endpoints, hence each variable must take a value that is at the endpoints. Crudely speaking, you can use a technique called smoothing, where you show that if $x_1, x_2 \neq 0 $, then we can increase the value by setting $ x_1 ^* = 0, x_2^* = x_1 + x_2$. This shows that at most 1 variable is non-zero.